# Vuetify - How can i save radio-buttons values in a variable

Tags: flask, routes, radio-button, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a form in Vuetify and Flask and i have some v-radio-groups. Each of these groups have 5 radio buttons where each one as a value associated. I pretend to collect the value selected in each group and send to another route. How can i do it? In this moment i have a submit button and i am using @click , but he doesn't do anything... Also, i think that i'm not saving well the radio buttons values.

Code of groups of v-radio-groups:

```
        <v-list-item v-for="(next, i) in questionsExceptFirst(questions)" :key="i">
          <v-container fluid>
            <p>{{next.text}}</p>
            <v-radio-group row :rules="[v => !!v || 'Item is required']" required >
              <v-radio v-for="n in 5" :key="n" :value="n" :label="`${n}`"/>
            </v-radio-group>
          </v-container>
        </v-list-item>
```

Comment: I have made a sandbox, but not quite sure if the solution is right for you? https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuetify-sandbox-7v6qm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @MaikenMadsen It's perfect! Thank you

Comment: I will just post it as a solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for a solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-radio-groups-with-one-v-model-7v6qm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark